# Kohana: передать параметр в экшен

Tags: php, kohana

Я только начинаю знакомство с данным фреймворком и у меня возникла проблема. Я установил его, в нес свои настройки, появился hello world, т.е. все оки. После чего пытаюсь вывести какой либо свой параметр, типа

```
public function action_index($name = 'anon')
{
    $this->response->body('hello, '.$name);
}
```

и всегда $name остается anon что бы я там не писал в адресной строке, разуметься если не поставить дефолтное значение то вылетает экзепшен. Фреймворк я установил в папку, басе урл и басе реврайт в хтацес я разумеется поменял на свои. Роуты использую по умолчанию, там по мимо класса и метода есть 1 передаваемый параметр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с Kohana 3.2 используется другой способ получения параметров:

```
$param = $this->request->param('name', 'anon');
```

Если будут возникать вопросы по Kohane, советую сайт: http://kohana3.ru/